# Windows phone 8.1 listbox with checkboxes duplicates selection

Tags: c#, checkbox, listbox

I created simple project which displays a listbox with items which include checkbox. When user selects checkbox of several items, some checkboxes below (outside of displayed area) are checked aswell without user interaction. This "phantom" selection occurs for items at approx. 30th position.

I tried:

- remove interface INotifyPropertyChanged from the class
- change ObservableCollection to List
- change ListView to GridView

With no effect.

```
Code:

Class_Test_CheckBox.cs

using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace App_Text_CheckBox
{
    public class Class_Test_CheckBox : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private Int64 _idPoint;
        private string _textContent;
        private bool _selected;
        private int _tag;

        public Int64 IdPoint
        {
            get { return _idPoint; }
            set
            {
                if (_idPoint != value)
                {
                    _idPoint = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("IdPoint");
                }
            }
        }

        public string TextContent
        {
            get { return _textContent; }
            set
            {
                if (_textContent != value)
                {
                    _textContent = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("TextContent");
                }
            }
        }

        public bool Selected
        {
            get { return _selected; }
            set
            {
                if (_selected != value)
                {
                    _selected = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Selected");
                }
            }
        }

        public int Tag
        {
            get { return _tag; }
            set
            {
                if (_tag != value)
                {
                    _tag = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Tag");
                }
            }
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}

Page_Test_CheckBox.xaml:

<Page
    x:Class="App_Text_CheckBox.Page_Test_CheckBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App_Text_CheckBox"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <!--Collection of items displayed by this page-->
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemsTestCheckBox"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- Title Panel -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="19,0,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="TEST APPLICATION" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Test CheckBox" Margin="0,-6.5,0,26.5" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" CharacterSpacing="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot" Margin="19,9.5,19,0">
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsTestCheckBox}}"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid Margin="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="cb_Test_CheckBox" Tag="{Binding Tag}" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" Checked="cb_Test_CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="cb_Test_CheckBox_Unchecked"  />
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Text="{Binding TextContent}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>

Page_Test_CheckBox.xaml.cs:

using App_Text_CheckBox.Common;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Basic Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=390556

namespace App_Text_CheckBox
{
     public sealed partial class Page_Test_CheckBox : Page
    {
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

        // Test ObservableCollection
        public ObservableCollection<Class_Test_CheckBox> ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox = new ObservableCollection<Class_Test_CheckBox>();

        public Page_Test_CheckBox()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;
        }

        public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
        {
            get { return this.navigationHelper; }
        }

        public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
        {
            get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
        }

        private void NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void NavigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region NavigationHelper registration

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            // Create 55 items
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 55; ii++)
            {
                Class_Test_CheckBox newItem = new Class_Test_CheckBox();
                newItem.IdPoint = (long)ii;
                newItem.Selected = false;       //for Binding CheckBox
                newItem.Tag = ii;
                newItem.TextContent = (ii + 1).ToString() + ". row - Lorem Ipsum Dolor ...";
                ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox.Add(newItem);
            }
            //items -> source
            itemsTestCheckBox.Source = ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        }

        #endregion

        private void cb_Test_CheckBox_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = (int)((sender as CheckBox).Tag);
            ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox[index].Selected = true;
            ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox[index].TextContent = (index + 1).ToString() + ". row - LOREM IPSUM DOLOR " + index.ToString() + " " + ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox[index].Selected.ToString();
        }

        private void cb_Test_CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = (int)((sender as CheckBox).Tag);
            ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox[index].Selected = false;
            ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox[index].TextContent = (index + 1).ToString() + ". row - lorem ipsum dolor " + index.ToString() + " " + ObservableCollection_Test_CheckBox[index].Selected.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

Is there any mistake, or how to avoid duplicate selection?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue.
This issue appears to be the result of virtualization being enabled.
There is a workaround but I still consider this a bug.

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510762/listview-applies-a-check-to-other-listview-items-having-a-checkbox-when-page-nav) regarding this issue: